# How to identify/Check the node exist or not in xml using XSLT, If exist modify the xml and print?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

This is sample input xml file i am using in xslt , how to check the particular nodes in the file , if it is present need to print True or false

```html
</persons>        
      '     <?xml version="1.0" ?>
       <persons>
        <person username="JS1">
         <name>John</name>
         <family-name>Smith</family-name>
        </person>
      <person username="MI1">
      <name>Morka</name>
      <family-name>Ismincius</family-name>
       </person>
     </persons>
```

Above sample xml file i Need to check `<name>` node present or not.  If name node present it should be print in the output using XSLT.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <persons>
  <person username="JS1">
    <name>John</name>
    <family-name>Smith</family-name>
  </person>
  <person username="MI1">
    <name>Morka</name>
    <family-name>Ismincius</family-name>
  </person>
    <person>
   **<name>True</name>**
   </person>
</persons>
```

Comment: Can any one help on this , Here check the node present in the xml or not using xslt and print the output xml file with node element true or false  <name>True</name>

Comment: The `name` element is present twice in your input, once for each `person`. Do you want to output `<name>True</name>` if `name` occurs at least once, or if it occurs for all `person` elements? Also note that your input XML is not well formed. As well as starting with a closing `</persons>` tag, the xml declaration needs to go right at the start. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the context item is a `<person>` element, then

`<xsl:copy-of select="name"/>`

will output the name element if it exists, and will do nothing if it does not exist.

If you want to output `<name>true</name>` if and only if there is at least one `<name>` element in the input, you can use

```
<xsl:if test="//name">
  <name>true</name>
</xsl:if>
```

If your requirement is different from that, then you will have to explain it much more clearly.